# Create PPT and DOC file in asp.net c# VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, powerpoint

I am a making web app in Asp.net c# where i need to generate pdf,doc and ppt.
For `PDF generation` i have used `Itext sharp` and it works fine, now i need to create `ppt` and `doc`. I dont know from where to start.

I tried this  http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/157867-Create-power-point-slide-charts-using-c-net.aspx
but its not working

pls provide any usefull resource or any other way to do achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need to do in with PowerPoint files, you may want to consider [SoftArtisans PowerPointWriter features](http://www.officewriter.com/powerpointwriter-features), which can populate a template with data and images. It  has some built-in behavior to automatically copy slides, tables, and lists to handle different amounts of data.

In one of the other answers, the tutorial covered how to replace text, how to replace an image, how to copy a slide, and how to delete a slide. Here is some information on how to do this with PowerPointWriter for reference:

- Importing text: [Hello World with PowerPointWriter](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/PPTW8/Hello+World+using+PowerPointTemplate)
- Importing images: [importing image reference](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/PPTW8/Importing+Images), [photo gallery code sample](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/PPTW8/Photo+Gallery)
- Copy slide: [Slides.CopySlide API reference](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/PPTW8/Slides.CopySlide%28PowerPointWriter.Slide,+Int%29), [CopySlide code sample](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/PPTW8/CopySlide)
- Deleting slide: [Slides.Delete API reference](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/PPTW8/Slides.Delete%28Int%29)

Disclaimer: I work for SoftArtisans.

Comment: @AlisonB- Thank for reply, but i am looking for opensource,